# Calculating thermodynamic properties with for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I try to calculate some thermodynamic properties with pyXSteam. I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pyXSteam.XSteam import XSteam
steamTable = XSteam(XSteam.UNIT_SYSTEM_MKS) 
df = pd.read_excel("XXXX", skiprows = 2)
Datum = df.iloc[5:8764,0]
T_ein= df.iloc[5:8764,3] #°C
P_ein=df.iloc[5:8764,5] #bara
mPkt_ein = df.iloc[5:8764,2] #kg/s
Tin_H = []
Tin_Q = []
for i in range(0,8765):
    Tin_H.append(steamTable.h_pt(P_ein[i],T_ein[i]))
    Tin_Q.append(Tin_H[i]*mPkt_ein[i])
#__________ Plot _____________________________
x = Datum
y = Tin_Q
plt.plot(x,y)
```

However I get the following error code. Can anybody tell me newbe what my mistake is?
Thank you for your support!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mowg.png)

Comment: Your error code is plain text. Don't post images of plain text.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
Tin_H.append(steamTable.h_pt(P_ein[i],T_ein[i]))
```

To:

```
Tin_H.append(steamTable.h_pt(P_ein.tolist()[i],T_ein.tolist()[i]))
```

**Edit:**

Now since you commented about the error on the next line, use:

```
Tin_Q.append(Tin_H[i]*mPkt_ein.tolist()[i])
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. Now I got the message for the next row, "Tin_Q". But here holist does not work

Comment: @Monica: Again Thank you. But I get the following error message "AttributeError: List object has no attribute "tolist""

Comment: @THZ Oh i know why, edited and should work now, remember to accept :P